# Help with Wifi problem on Acer Aspire One 532h update to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wireless, upgrade, acer

I just upgraded to 11.10 and extremely frustratingly cannot keep a stable connection to ANY WLAN.

It will connect, then disconnect, then connect, making anything that requires the internet impossible.

I have run "rfkill list" with this output:

```
0: acer-wireless: Wireless Lan
Soft-blocked: no
Hard-blocked: no
1: phy0:  Wireless LAn
Soft-blocked: no
Hard-blocked: no
```

I have installed b43 firmware but that doesn't work.   <strike>Will try the BCMWL-kernel-source and see what happens.</strike>  Just tried that and didn't work.

Meanwhile, anyone have any good ideas?

Will there be a patch to fix this?

Comment: What is the output from: **sudo lshw -C network** and **iwconfig**?  This may be resolved by blacklisting, but need more details.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to fix this if your hardware is bcm4312 you just need the correct firmware

open terminal and type:

```
sudo su -

apt-get install firmware-b43-lpphy-installer

apt-get remove --purge bcmwl-kernel-source

apt-get autoremove --purge
```

the last one will clean dependency created by bcmwl << which is the STA driver.

reboot - and you-re done.